# How to optimize code for show() and hide() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have a register form. I'm using jQuery. But now my code is very long, I want to make it smaller. But I'm not very good at jQuery. In my register form, you should select from 3 radio buttons - for student, teacher or coord. If you're a student, you should see first dropdown with regions, next - dropdown with schools, next -with teachers and finally - with classes. If you're a teacher, you should see these dropdowns but without "teacher" dropdown. If you're a coord, you should see only list of all teachers.
Now I've made if if you are student or if you're teacher or coordinator, to calls different methods.How to combine them in a few methods, not different for different radio buttons? And I have to hide all first and then show different functions. Because now if I click on the first radio button and next click on the third radio button, it shows me the dropdowns which are only for the first radio, but not for the last radio button.
 My code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      function showHide(self, show){
        

          if (show)
              $('.toggle').show();
          else
              $('.toggle').hide();
          $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
          $(self).prop('checked',true);
      }
   
   
     
      function teacher_role(self, show){
          if (show)
              $('.region').show();
          else
              $('.region').hide();
          $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
          $(self).prop('checked',true);
      }
     

      function show(yes, no){
          if (no)
              $('.school').show();
          else
              $('.school').hide();
          $("region").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }

     function school_show(yes, no){
        if (no)
              $('.teacher').show();
          else
              $('.teacher').hide();
          $("school").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }
       function class_show(yes, no){
        if (no)
              $('.class').show();
          else
              $('.class').hide();
          $("teacher").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }
       function teacher_school_show(self, show){
          if (show)
              $('.teacher_school').show();
          else
              $('.teacher_school').hide();
          $("region").prop('checked',false);
          $(self).prop('checked',true);
      }
      function teacher_class_show(yes, no){
        if (no)
              $('.teacher_class').show();
          else
              $('.teacher_class').hide();
          $("teacher").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }    
 function teachers_show(yes, no){
          if (no)
              $('.all_teachers_show').show();
          else
              $('.all_teachers_show').hide();
          $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
          $(yes).prop('checked',true);
      }
      
    
  </script>   
 
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#region').change(function() {
                var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_schools";
                var postdata = {region: $('#region').val()};
                $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                    var $school_sel = $('#school');
                    $school_sel.empty();
                    $school_sel.append("<option>Please choose region</option>");
                    var schools_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    $.each(schools_obj, function(key, val) {
                        var option = '<option  value="' + val.school_id + '">' + val.school_name + '</option>';
                        $school_sel.append(option);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
   
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#school').change(function() {
                var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_teachers";
                var postdata = {school: $('#school').val()};
                $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                    var $teacher_sel = $('#teacher');
                    $teacher_sel.empty();
                    $teacher_sel.append("<option>Please choose school</option>");
                    var teachers_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    $.each(teachers_obj, function(key, val) {
                        var option = '<option value="' + val.user_id + '">' + val.username + '</option>';
                        $teacher_sel.append(option);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
  
    </head>
<body>
<?php
  
  echo validation_errors();
  echo "<div class='container'>";
  echo form_open('home/register');
//some inputs
echo "<tr><td>  Choose role:*  </td><td>";

  echo form_radio('role_id[]', '1', FALSE, 'onClick="showHide(this, true)"');
  echo " Student ";
  echo form_radio('role_id[]', '2', FALSE, 'onClick="teacher_role(this, true)"');
  echo " Teacher ";
   echo form_radio('role_id[]', '5', FALSE, 'onClick="teachers_show(this, true)"');
  echo " Coordinator ";
  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr class='toggle' style='display:none;'><td>  Region:*  </td><td>";
  ?>

  <select name='region' id='region' onClick="show(this, true)">
      <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
        <option value= "<?= $row->region ?>"><?= $row->region ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
  <?php
  echo "</td></tr>";


   echo "<tr class='region' style='display:none;'><td>  Region:*  </td><td>";
  ?>

  <select name='region' id='region' onClick="teacher_school_show(this, true)">
      <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
        <option value= "<?= $row->region ?>"><?= $row->region ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
  <?php
  echo "</td></tr>";



  echo "<tr class='school' style='display:none;' onClick='school_show(this, true)'><td>  School:*  </td><td>";  
  echo '<select id="school" name="school[]">';
  echo '<option name="school[]">Please choose region</option>';
  echo '</select>';
  
  echo "</td></tr>";




  echo "<tr class='teacher_school' style='display:none;' onClick='teacher_class_show(this, true)'><td>  School:*  </td><td>";  
  echo '<select id="school" name="school[]">';
  echo '<option name="school[]">Please choose region</option>';
  echo '</select>';
  
  echo "</td></tr>";



  echo "<tr class='teacher' style='display:none;' onClick='class_show(this, true)'><td>  Учител:*  </td><td>";
  
  echo '<select id="teacher" name="teacher[]">';
  echo '<option >Please choose school</option>';
  echo '</select>';
  
  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr class='class' style='display:none;'><td>  Class:*  </td><td>";

  ?>
   <select name='class[]' id='class'>
      <?php foreach ($classes as $row) { ?>
        <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->class_id ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
 
   <select name='class_divisions[]' id='class_divisions'>
    <?php foreach ($class_divisions as $row) { ?>
 <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->division ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
  </td></tr>


  <tr class='teacher_class' style='display:none;'><td>  Класен ръководител:*  </td><td>

  
   <select name='class[]' id='class'>
      <?php foreach ($classes as $row) { ?>
        <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->class_id ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
 
   <select name='class_divisions[]' id='class_divisions'>
    <?php foreach ($class_divisions as $row) { ?>
 <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->division ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
  </select> 
  </td></tr>



  <?php
  echo "<tr class='all_teachers_show' style='display:none;'><td>  Teachers:*  </td><td>";
  ?>
 
    <?php foreach ($all_teachers_show as $row) { ?>
 
  <input type="checkbox" id='all_teachers_show' name="all_teachers_show[]"
   value="<?= $row->user_id ?>"><?= $row->username ?>
      <?php } ?>
 

<?php
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "</table><br/>";
  $data=array(
    "name" => 'mysubmit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-success ',
    'id' => 'reg',
    'value' => 'Register'
  );
  echo form_submit($data);
  ?>
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>
   
  </html>
```

Comment: There is no relation between your question subtitle and question desc i eagerly open the link

Comment: A fiddle would be really helpful in this case as it looks like you just need optimizations, not a rewrite

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a0vguvr8/14/  - but its'not working here, what's wrong with it?

Comment: girl89 it looks like you've created that fiddle with php in it.  If this is a question about jQuery, copy your generated HTML output into a fiddle so we can help you with this question

Comment: I updated my fiddle. I put html markup. I don't know why JS is not working there. However, have you some ideas how to optimize my code and hide everything and then show particular functions that are different for the three radio buttons? :)